# Pull data from HTML dropdown

Tags: html, vba

I'm looking for a way to extract data from the available options from a website dropdown box, specifically the second optgroup "All fund companies".

extract of HTML code I'm scraping

```
</div><div class="large-5 medium-5 columns spacer-bottom padding-left-none"><div class="select_wrap"><select id="search-company" name="companyid" class="default">
<option value="">Search by company</option>
<optgroup label="Popular companies">
    <option value="4">Hargreaves Lansdown</option>
    <option value="1908">Lindsell Train</option>
    <option value="55">Jupiter</option>
    <option value="191">Legal & General</option>
    </optgroup>
<optgroup label="All fund companies">
    <option value="218">Aberdeen</option>
    <option value="1080">Aberforth Unit Trust Managers</option>
    <option value="141">Allianz Global Investors</option>
    <option value="3472">Alquity Investment Management Limited</option>
    <option value="1324">Amati Global Investors Ltd</option>
```

VBA:

```
Set htmlObj = html.getElementById("search-company")

For Each Child In htmlObj.getElementByClassName("optgroup")(1).Children
    sqlId = Child.Value
    sqlCompany = Child.innerText
    Debug.Print (sqlId & " - " & sqlCompany)
Next
```

Comment: optgroup is not a class name; it is an element or more accurately a child element of the select element with the search-company id.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeeped...

This is the code that managed to solve the problem... not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it, but it works :)

```
    Set htmlObj = html.getElementById("search-company")

    For Each Child In htmlObj.Children
        If Child.Label = "All fund companies" Then Set htmlObj2 = Child
    Next

    For Each Child In htmlObj2.Children
        sqlId = Child.Value
        sqlCompany = Child.innerText
        Debug.Print (sqlId & " - " & sqlCompany)
    Next
```